# The Dreaded ClassNotFoundException for MapFragment

Tags: android, maps, classnotfoundexception, google-play-services, mapfragment

I'm facing a very frustrating problem here with the android ADT.  I have a project which is using google maps which I have been working on for a few months. I have everything working perfectly on my existing laptop - an x86 winxp box.  I'm attempting to migrate all my dev environment to my slick new x64 win7 laptop.

I can not get past the dreaded ClassNotFoundException for MapFragment at runtime when the activity inflates. I had no problem solving this issue on the old box.  I followed the instructions given in hundreds of posts here and elsewhere on adding the google play services lib and referencing it and it worked perfectly.  Well, I'm doing exactly the same stuff on the new box but I can not get this to work.

It's clear that lots of stuff is simply not getting packaged to the APK.  It is about 1/2 the size on the new laptop compared to that on the old one.  I just have no idea why.

The ADT package on the new box is version 22 while it's version 21 on the x86 box.  I do see that the eclipse project looks slightly different.  There is a "Android Private Libraries" folder on the project on the new box.

I'm searching everywhere for an answer but everything just points me to doing what I have already done.  There has got to be something different about how the build works on this x64 version of the apt.

Does anyone have any ideas for me?  I'm about ready to mothball the new laptop and just move back to the old one so I can keep working.  I've burned up about 5 evenings on this issue so far.

here are screenshots of the project on the two machines.  Top is the x86 project which works great.  bottom is the x64 project which is leaving all kinds of stuff out of the apk.

Apparently I am not reputable enough to post images so here are links:

The x86 project which works great:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70407965/x86proj.jpg

The x64 project which does not:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70407965/x64proj.jpg

Much appreciation for any help.  I'm really out of ideas on this.

Comment: In java build path check the new library that update 22 put in there

Comment: And in sdk manager make sure you have the build tools downloaded, since the update there has been a million posts of these problems

Answer (score 0):

go to

> your app "properties"
> "Order and Import"
> check "Android Private Libraries"
(it is unchecked by default)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I actually came to the same conclusion this morning.  I created a new project from scratch and then copied my src, res, libs, and manifest file in.  It worked perfectly.  Then I beyond-compared the project files and saw that the dependencies were exported in the from-scratch project.  My only issue now is that the app signature has apparently changed so my map and blogger auths don't work. I guess I have to go back to the apis control panel and add the new signature